# How to add a dynamically changing float value to a label

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I'm coding this app that pulls your battery % and shows it to the user periodically. I've made it work so far as a console app, but as I re-write it in Windows Forms it gives me some issues when using the labels to display the value.

*Edit: I have included the changes Niranjan Kala pointed out as I was using more than one label for this, but it still doesn't work*

*Also, as he has requested, I have added more of the program layout so as to provide some context and maybe find the error*

This is what it looks like:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form 
{ 

public Form1() 

{ InitializeComponent(); 

// Imagine all the visual stuff going here (icons and menus, etc.)

//I start the thread
batThing = new Thread(new ThreadStart(batThing)); 
batThing.Start();
 }


 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Type power = typeof(PowerStatus);
        PropertyInfo[] pi = power.GetProperties();


            #region Cargador


        //0 = PowerLineStatus --> Charger on or not?
        object EdeCargador = pi[0].GetValue(SystemInformation.PowerStatus, null);

        //turns charger state into int
        int edc = Convert.ToInt32(EdeCargador);

        int On = Convert.ToInt32(PowerLineStatus.Online);
        On = 1;
        int Off = Convert.ToInt32(PowerLineStatus.Offline);
        Off = 0;
        int Unk = Convert.ToInt32(PowerLineStatus.Unknown);
        Unk = 255;

        if (edc == On)
        {
            string CargadorConectado = "-Cargador Conectado-";
            label2.Text = CargadorConectado;
            string EdeBateria2 = "-Cargando-";
            label4.Text = EdeBateria2;
        }
        else
        {
            string CargadorDesconectado = "-Cargador Desconectado-";
            label2.Text = CargadorDesconectado;
            #endregion

            #region Cantidad de Bateria

            //3 = BatteryLifePercent --> tells the % of bat available
            object CantdeBat = pi[3].GetValue(SystemInformation.PowerStatus, null);

            //string to float , then * 100 to get a %
            float num = (Single.Parse(CantdeBat.ToString())) * 100;

            // shows a % and says if battery is full or low
            string EdeBateria = num.ToString() + "%";

            if (num == 100)
            {
                EdeBateria = "-Batería Completa-";
                label4.Text = EdeBateria;
            }
            else if (num <= 25)
            {
                EdeBateria = "-Batería Baja. Conecte el cargador-";
                label4.Text = EdeBateria;

            }
            else if (num > 25 & num < 100)
            {
                //nada
            }

            if (num <= 0)
            {
                EdeBateria = "No tenes bateria gil";
                label4.Text = EdeBateria;
            }



        }
        #endregion

        #region Tiempo Restante
        //4 = BatteryLifeRemaining --> Indicates the remaining battery time
        object TdeBat = pi[4].GetValue(SystemInformation.PowerStatus, null);

            double tiempobat = (Double.Parse(TdeBat.ToString()));

            if (tiempobat == -1)
            {
                string NoHayBat = "El equipo no está operando a través de una batería";
                label5.Text = NoHayBat;
            }
            else if (tiempobat != -1)
            {
                //gets time in seconds and turns it into hours , min and secs
                TimeSpan t = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(tiempobat);
                string TiempoRestante = string.Format("El tiempo de uso restante es de: {0:D1} horas, {1:D2} minutos y {2:D2} segundos",
                 t.Hours,
                 t.Minutes,
                 t.Seconds
                 );

                label5.Text = TiempoRestante ;


            }
            #endregion

    } // fin de form1
```

*Edit: I have found that there are certain issues when jumping from one method from another, for instance, the problem I originally had, which was with 'label 4' I came to find that was due to the logic in the charger state, so I added this:*

```
  string EdeBateria2 = "-Cargando-";
            label4.Text = EdeBateria2;
```

After adding this when I have the charger connected it displays so nicely, but when I disconnect the charger entering the 'else' where I coded the conditionals for label 4 the problems begin.

The strings in both label 2 and label 5 change dinamically as I disconnect the charger out of the laptop PC with no problems whatsoever, the issue is with label 4 still. As I disconnect the charger it stops displaying the message I define as '-Cargando-' and it just shows its name 'label4'.

I'm stuck, any ideas?

I'm using C# in VS 2015.

Comment: why are you using multiple labels. you should use only one label.. and then update it's text with your desired string.

Comment: are you sure all labels are updated in your code path

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display status then it should be like this. Create status of the battery and then update to the label. check this sample snippet and then update it according to your requirement..

```
object BatQuantity= pi[3].GetValue(SystemInformation.PowerStatus, null);

//convert the value I get from PowerStatus class to %
float num = (Single.Parse(CantdeBat.ToString())) * 100;

//shows battery % and if battery is full says it's full if not it says it's low
string batteryStatus = num.ToString() + "%";
if (num == 100)
{
    batteryStatus = "-Full Battery-";
}
else if (num <= 25)
{           
    batteryStatust = "-Low Battery-";
}            
label4.Text = batteryStatust;
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Great, even though I'm using 1 label to display multiple states in other functions it didn't occur to me to do so in this case for some reason lol. So, I did what you suggested and sadly it still doesn't show the string but 'label4' instead. I don't really know what to do, doesn't even recognize an error with the coding so I'd appreciate any other ideas. Thanks!

Comment: I updated your suggestions to the original question, if you have any more ideas I'll be thankful!

Comment: are you trying to update it from any background thread. or what else. if you are updating it on UI thread then it must update the text of the label. it would be better if you provide more information about the program flow and label existence on the form.

Comment: I have added more context to the original code as you asked, I am new to coding, and perhaps I made a mistake like you said. Don't know much about threading.

Comment: write your actual code sample.. it this thread code is used in program??

Comment: this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate()
                {
                    label4.Text = batteryStatust;
                    }
                });  put this in another method and call it in batThing method also to update the label text.

Comment: So I actually found that there's a conflict somehow between the different conditionals I've added throught the program

Comment: I've updated the code , adding the complete layout of the logic I use in my program. This should make it a lot easier to figure out where I'm making the mistake.